# Fax on HP Officejet

Tags: fax, hp-officejet

I'd like to know if it was possible to setup my HP Officejet Pro 8630 as a fax machine on my cable service's telephone plan. I currently have Time Warner Cable as my telephone supplier. I want it to automatically detect a fax and **not ring my home phone line**. My cable company says I will need to purchase a separate line, which I do not believe is necessary. Is this possible? If so, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We need some clarification on some things. What do you mean "lanline"? Did you mean **land line**, as in a regular telephone line? Or did you mean **LAN line**? Are you getting your telephone service thru your cable company? Please [edit] your question with these details. Do not answer my questions with a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This question is almost off topic. But since it has to do with an HP Officejet, I will say "Yes, it is possible".

Typically, to avoid fax calls ringing on a phone, you need a separate line so the call goes direct to the fax. That is the preferred solution by your provider. To avoid the cost and hassle of a second line, there are devices called fax switches.

A fax switch senses the call type and sends it to the proper device. Since those types of devices are off topic here, all I can say is do a search for "fax switch" and you will find all types of them. A search on Amazon resulted in over 100 results.

**Disclaimer: Although it should work, I make no guarantee any of these devices will work with your setup.**